# stub out :destroy for deleting public_activity record in request spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, factory-bot

I have a destroy method in my AnswersController which also destroys a public_activity record when its trackable object is deleted.

Answers Controller activity delete:

```
 def destroy
    @answer = Answer.find(params[:id])
    if @answer.destroy 
       @activity = PublicActivity::Activity.where(trackable_id: @answer.id, trackable_type: "Answer", owner_id: @answer.user.id).first
       @activity.destroy
       respond_to do |format|
          format.js
       end
    end
 end
```

My answers_spec.rb test fails with:

```
Answers deletes an answer
 Failure/Error: click_link "delete-answer"
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method 'destroy' for nil:NilClass
 # ./app/controllers/answers_controller.rb:41:in `destroy'
 # (eval):2:in 'click_link'
 # ./spec/requests/answers_spec.rb:20:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/requests/answers_spec.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I presume this is because the `@activity` instance variable you can see in the `AnswersController` hasn't been set and there is no public activity record to attempt to delete.

Is there a way to either create the `@activity` instance variable with the answers credentials so it can be deleted or a way to stub out the destroy method so the public_activity record isn't deleted?

**answers_spec.rb**

```
//omitted for brevity//

it "deletes an answer" do
    visit root_path
    sign_in_user
    create_and_find_question
    create_answer
    page.should have_selector("div", id: "delete-answer")
    expect {
      click_link "delete-answer"
    }.to change(Answer, :count).by(-1)
  end
```

**answer_helper.rb**

```
module AnswerHelper
  def create_and_find_question
    visit questions_path
    click_link "Ask a Question"
    page.should have_content "Step 1: Upload a Video"
    click_link "Step 2"
    page.should have_content "Step 2: Ask your question"
    fill_in "Title", with: "Ball starting too far left"
    fill_in "Body", with: "my clubface is closed..."
    expect {
      click_button "Save"
    }.to change(Question, :count).by(1) 
    page.should have_content "Question Created"
    page.should have_content "Add your answer"
  end

  def create_answer
    click_link "Add your answer"
    page.should have_selector("div", id: "new_answer")
    fill_in "answer_body", with: "You need to shift your weight better"
    expect {
      click_button "Save Answer"
    }.to change(Answer, :count).by(1) 
    page.should have_content "You need to shift your weight better"
  end
 end
```

**Update**

As per Peter's comment below, it would make sense to use rails inbuilt dependent destroy to handle deleting associated records. I have just tried to add this into the answers model:

has_many :activities, as: :trackable, dependent: :destroy

however it errors out with:
 `NameError - uninitialized constant Answer::Activity:`

The PublicActivity table is called activities. What name should I be using for this has_many association?

Comment: It's not clear to me what your trying to do. Could you explain what is your goal?

Comment: My request spec fails with undefined method destroy for nil class. So I want to either stub the destroy method or set the @activity instance variable so that the activity can be deleted.

Comment: Your first code fragment follows a statement about delete, but just shows an assignment statement. Was there more code you intended to share here?

Comment: Can you share the stack trace and associated code to see where the `nil` reference is coming from?

Comment: Yes you are bot correct, sorry for the confusion, the question has been refactored and simplified. both delete and stack trace now present.

Comment: When you just "use" your application through the browser without going through rspec (i.e. following the same steps), do you encounter this problem?  As an aside, Rails will take care of deleting dependent records through the use of the `dependent: destroy` argument to `has_one` and `has_many`.

Comment: Nope, just rspec as that instance variable isn't set in the request spec, the delete action works as expected in the browser, but the dependent destroy is a really good point. Ill give that a try thanks Peter.

Comment: I'm confused by that. That instance variable is set in the controller's `delete` method as a result of the `where` call, so if it works in the browser, it seems to me it should work in RSpec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I think you should still try and figure out what is going wrong with your explicit delete, since it may indicate a problem elsewhere in your code, I'm going to respond here to your question about the use of `has_many`.

I think you're getting the `NameError` because the default name for the associated class (i.e. an unqualified `Activity`, derived from the word `activities`) is not correct. The associated class is `PublicActivity::Activity`. You can specify it with the `class_name` parameter, as described in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-has-many.  Note that you specify the associated class and let Rails deduce the associated table name; you do not specific the table name directly.

Comment: I'm glad this answer was acceptable/helpful, but I'm still really curious about your original failure. Please do share back if you ever figure it out.

Comment: Hi Peter, thank you for this, this is the proper elegant solution to the problem. I am still looking at why the original code was failing in the tests. I had to set that instance variable in the controller tests in order for them to pass, why this needed to happen is the mystery atm, but ill report back if i find anything. Thanks again.

Comment: One other thought. Did you confirm that the `nil` dereference was on the `@activity.destroy` and not earlier in the `Answer#destroy` method? Your trace indicated line 41, but your code fragment didn't have line numbers. In any event, you might want to print out the arguments to the preceding `where` call to see if they all make sense.

Comment: Hi Peter, yes line 41 represented the @activity IVAR rather than the previous call to destroy for the trackable object. The preceding destroy call, has worked as expected "live" and in a test environment.

Comment: What does IVAR mean? Also, I don't know what "previous call to destroy" refers to. You showed two lines, the first was `@activity = ...` and the second was `@activity.destroy`.  Was one of these two lines #41?

Comment: Hi Peter, sorry, ivar = instance variable, i've added the line which precedes @activity.destroy + where query in the question.

Comment: Ok, thanks. How about putting some `puts` calls in Activity#destroy to validate/compare the behavior via the browser vs. rspec? Looking at the code, one thing that jumps out is the possibility that @answer.destroy returns false in the case of the browser. You could also print the arguments to the `where` call and compare the two cases.